# Warning: Can't call setState on a component that is not yet mounted

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs, setstate

I am getting this warning when I tried to change the setstate input value while unit testing(jest)

Warning: Can't call setState on a component that is not yet mounted. This is a no-op, but it might indicate a bug in your application. Instead, assign to `this.state` directly or define a `state = {};` class property with the desired state in the Login component.
My code is:

```
this.onChangeEvent = this.onChangeEvent.bind(this);

this.state = { email: '' }

componentDidMount() { this.onChangeEvent(); }

componentWillUnmount() { }

onChangeEvent(event) {     
    this.setState({ email: e.target.value });     
}
```

I couldn't find right solution for this warning. Can someone help me to resolve this warning?

Comment: What does your component look like?

Comment: better post your code to REPL and share link

Comment: Please, include a [mcve]. The code in your question right now is incomplete or simply invalid syntax.

Comment: @chauhanamit the code should be in the question description, either as a code block or a [runnable stack snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/269753/1218980). Using off-site resources is discouraged.

Answer (score 2):

*Context binding* and *state initialization* must be done inside the `constructor`.

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.onChangeEvent = this.onChangeEvent.bind(this);

    this.state = { email: '' }
}
```

Comment: Class instance fields are now mostly supported in CRA and Next.js default babel configuration, so you can avoid the `constructor` altogether and still use `this`.

Comment: I was aware of that for `state initialization` but is possible for `bindings` as well?

Comment: Something like `class C { state = {}; onEvent = () => this.setState({}); }`

Comment: Using `arrow functions`. But what about `class methods`?

Comment: In my comment, `onEvent` is a class property which value is an arrow function, which is equivalent to an already bound class method.

Comment: I know that, due to lexical `this` arrow functions doesn't have to be binded, (I only use arrow functions as well), but for curiosity, if I want to use plain old `class methods` I must bind them in `constructor` right?

Comment: But why use a plain old class methods when you're just going to pass them around as callbacks?

Comment: No reason, just out of curiosity

Comment: If you really don't have a choice, I guess that you could either `bind` like in your answer, or just wrap the method in a callback like `<button onClick={() => this.method()} />`

Comment: I don't see the point of using `class methods` as well. Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
class App extends Component {
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        email: ""
    }
}
onChangeEvent(event) {
    this.setState({
        email: event.target.value
    });
}
render() {
    const {
        email
    } = this.state;
    return ( <div className = "App">
        <input type = "text"
        onChange = { this.onChangeEvent.bind(this)}
        value = {email}/>
        </div>
    );
 }
}
```

Comment: I am getting this error, when I run 'npm run test'. I am trying to test 'whether there is a value in email or not' using jest.                                                                       
                                                                                                                         
 Warning: Can't call setState on a component that is not yet mounted. This is a no-op, but it might indicate a bug in your application. Instead, assign to `this.state` directly or define a `state = {};` class property with the desired state in the Login component.

Comment: I set email as null in state, and in my test code I have given some value. But the given value is not being updated and returning as null with the above error. How can I update the setstate email value?

Comment: please provide your component code for better understanding.

Comment: My test function is:                                                                     
 `describe('email', () => {                                                                            
   it('should return email', () => {
     
      'let login = new Login();

     'const state = {
        'email: ''
      };
       
      let e = {
        target: {
          value: 'emailvalue'
        }
      }

      login.onChangeevent(e);
      expect(state.email).toBe(e.target.value);
     })

Comment: My function is: constructor(props) {
        super(props)
        this.state = {
            email: ''
        }
    } onChangeEvente(e) {
        this.setState({ email: e.target.value }, () => {

        })
    }

Comment: SetState is not updating as per my test input. Can someone help to fix this?